# Vim How to turn off this screen and go to another screen

Tags: vim

[image]

I used the :term command in Vim.

but i can't escape from that.

Comment: Lifehack #XXX: before you execute a command for the first time, read up on what it does and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are typing in the terminal, you are in the "terminal" mode. You can press `<C-\><C-N>` (`Ctrl+\`, and then `Ctrl+N`) to enter the "normal" mode. After that you will be able to switch the windows, with e.g., `<C-W> j`.

You can read `:help terminal-input` about this. In particular, it explains how to use `Esc` (instead of `<C-\><C-N>`) to escape the terminal mode if you want.